# Trouble with making a wing on a dragon

Tags: modeling, vertices

So I am trying to recreate a dragon called Toothless from the movie How To Train Your Dragon. But i'm having some trouble connecting his inner wing plate thing to his back. The vertices have five connections where it connects the wing and back, but I need that - as far as i know - so that I can give the wing plates physics, and make it look right.

Here's a look at the body in Object mode:
[image: Here's a look at the body in Object mode]

I do have a subsurf as you should on almost anything, and that bends but hiding that and then normalizing the geometry. No changes. Tried sculpting it away. No result.

Here's a look in edit mode with Limit selection to visible disabled:
[image: The selected vertex is one of the once that connect to the body and wing]
I am in now way an good at blender, so i'm just looking for some advice :)
I have a felling that it's something to do with the subsurf, but i'm kinda lost :/

Comment: You have to delete the interior faces:
https://i.imgur.com/k3zok4C.png

Comment: Well, they are not interior, they are the dragon's body.. So you need to model the wing as it has volume - top and bottom surface. What you have is non-manifold surface and it will produce artifacts.

Comment: @Jerryno That sounds extremely cool and sounds so logical when i thing about it. Thank you a lot :D